# Win11: Manual DNS settings in VPN does not apply

Tags: networking, vpn, dns

I would like to connect to a VPN and manually configure DNS settings in Win11:

[image: Screenshot: VPN Settings]

I've disabled ipv6, and manually set DNS server addresses.

However, when I executed `nslookup` in CMD, I got

```
Default Server:  [Default hostname set by the VPN provider]
Address:   [Default address set by the VPN provider]
```

instead of the expected address:

```
Default Server: [Expected Server Name / Unknown]
Address:  223.5.5.5
```

How can I change correctly my DNS servers, or force the system globally to use the DNS I want?

My system version:

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 23H2
OS build    22631.3296
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22687.1000.0
```